# How to reduce risk of flooded /POST request in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a simple `/post` request in my nodejs app (nodejs + mongodb).

However, Im really afraid of ddos attack or just a simple attack with clicking rapidly `send request` button in Postman to my app which could result in app performance or even crash it.

Can it be done with `cors` policy? Can I somehow tell the app to accept only these posts which comes directly from my domain?

I did something like:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
   res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'https://example.com');
   res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');
   next();
});
```

But it still accepts every /post from postman. Looking forward for any hints. Thanks.

Comment: "Can it be done with cors policy? Can I somehow tell the app to accept only these posts which comes directly from my domain?" — No and No.

Answer (score 2):

CORS is a directive to browsers which instructs them to prevent making requests to your API from unauthorized domains. CORS is in no way enforced by the server so apps like postman dont need to respect CORS directives. That being said CORS also has nothing to do with rate limiting.

I think you probably want a rate limiter library (like `express-rate-limit`) if you want to make DOS harder. In addition you should debounce your submit button in the app (this is just good practice)

Comment: Thanks but whats the point to debounce my submit button if user can simply click submit button in postman without any throttle? :P

Comment: Its a UX issue, a user normally only intends one click of a submit button, so you should lock it out after they click until they edit again.